# Dynamic attachment filename

Tags: apache, httpd.conf

I have a apache2 server and, behind it, another server that serves some PDF files with legal notices. The URLs are formed like this :

`mycompany.com/documents?doc=the_document_name.pdf`

Every browser understands that the file must be downloaded except Safari on iPhone that displays it instead of downloading. So, I use some Apache conf in order to modify `Content-Type / Content-Disposition` headers :

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    <If "%{REQUEST_URI} =~ /documents/ && %{QUERY_STRING} =~ /.*\.pdf/">
        Header set Content-Type application/octect-stream
        Header set Content-Disposition attachment
    </If>
</IfModule>
```

It works fine except that the downloaded document has no name when downloaded from Safari/iPhone.

So, I would like to add `filename=${name_of_the_document}` and capture the document name from the request via a regex but I cannot find how to achieve it.

Here is what I have so far :

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    <If "%{REQUEST_URI} =~ /documents/ && %{QUERY_STRING} =~ /.*\.pdf/">
        Define MY_FILE download.pdf // <-- Here, how do I capture the file name ?
        Header set Content-Type application/octect-stream
        Header set Content-Disposition 'attachment; filename=${MY_FILE}'
    </If>
</IfModule>
```